# parameters with special characters in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl, awk

We have the following CSV file,

file include parameter and value

```
      more hadoop.txt

      security.admin.protocol.acl,*
      security.client.protocol.acl,***
      xasecure.add-hadoop-authorization,true
      ranger.plugin.hdfs.policy.rest.ssl.config.file,/etc/hadoop/conf/ranger-policymgr-ssl.xml,
      ranger.plugin.hdfs.policy.source.impl,org.apache.ranger.admin.client.RangerAdminRESTClient
      ranger.plugin.hdfs.policy.cache.dir,/etc/ranger/{{repo_name}}/policycache",
      ranger.plugin.hdfs.policy.pollIntervalMs,@$!!
      ranger.plugin.hdfs.service.name,{{repo_name}}
```

the following code is part of my bash script:

```
while read -r line 
do 

param=` echo $line |  awk -F ',' '{print $1}' `
val=` echo $line |  awk -F ',' '{print $2}' `
echo $val
if [[ $val = $hadoop_val ]]
them

done < $hadoop.txt
```

the problem is when val is **"*" or "@$!!"** or other special characters then we get different value from:

```
echo $val
```

how to improve the code in order to get the original values as "*" or "@$!!" from echo $val

Comment: Could you indent your file properly?

Comment: Please clean up all those dots and white space and simply post a script that reproduces whatever problem you're asking about (i.e. a [mcve]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent special characters to be expanded, you can enclose your variable between double quotes. As an aside you don't have to use awk, just change the IFS:

```
IFS=,
while read -r param val 
do
    echo "$val"
done < doop.log
```